# Parse.com Error Code 111 on save

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm experiencing an intermittent error with an app I'm writing. I'm using JavaScript with Parse.com as the back-end.

I have an array of objects. For example:

```
[
   {
       "skillBase": 96,
       "skillName": "First Aid"
    },
    {
       "skillBase": 96,
       "skillName": "Communication"
    }
]
```

I have three rows in Parse.com of a model called "Character". One of the columns for Character is of type Array named "baseSkills".

I generate the array of objects and save it to the back-end using the first of the three Characters, no problem. However, I cannot save similar arrays to the second and third Characters. I keep getting this error:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Character/Zoi6QD14M6 400 (Bad Request)
parse.js:1551 
Parse._ajax
parse.js:1649 Parse._request
parse.js:5590 (anonymous function)
parse.js:4055 (anonymous function)
parse.js:3895 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3957 (anonymous function)
parse.js:3940 runLater
parse.js:3956 _.extend.then
parse.js:4054 _.extend._continueWith
parse.js:5578 _.extend.saveskills.js:833 (anonymous function)
parse.js:3895 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3839 (anonymous function)
parse.js:95 _.each._.forEach
parse.js:3838 _.extend.resolve
parse.js:3900 (anonymous function)
parse.js:3895 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3957 (anonymous function)
parse.js:3940 runLater
parse.js:3956 _.extend.then
parse.js:3899 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3839 (anonymous function)
parse.js:95 _.each._.forEach
parse.js:3838 _.extend.resolve
parse.js:3905 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3839 (anonymous function)
parse.js:95 _.each._.forEach
parse.js:3838 _.extend.resolve
parse.js:3905 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3839 (anonymous function)
parse.js:95 _.each._.forEach
parse.js:3838 _.extend.resolve
parse.js:3900 (anonymous function)
parse.js:3895 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3957 (anonymous function)
parse.js:3940 runLater
parse.js:3956 _.extend.then
parse.js:3899 wrappedResolvedCallback
parse.js:3839 (anonymous function)
parse.js:95 _.each._.forEach
parse.js:3838 _.extend.resolve
parse.js:1536 xhr.onreadystatechange
skills.js:844 Error Code: 111
```

If I take the array of objects and manually enter it via Parse.com's web interface, it accepts it.

When I pass an array of objects that are valid first Character to the second and third Characters, I get the above error. If I do the opposite - take the array of objects of the second or third Character and apply them to the first character, it is accepted.This is why I labeled the problem intermittent, though that may be a bit misleading.

I find this puzzling because my research suggests that Error 111 is a Type error; as if the data type I'm passing does not match my configuration on the back-end. Yet the column expects an array, and I'm reasonably sure I'm passing it an array.

Here is some sample code that will fail with "400 Bad Request":

```
var testArr =  [{"foo": 5},{"bar": 7}];

character.set("charBaseSkills", testArr);
character.save().then(function(character) {
    d.resolve(character);
});
```

If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions, they are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show more code?

Comment: @eth3lbert I am happy to, but I'm not sure what code would be helpful. This particular file is 867 lines, so I'm not sure which part would be relevant to the question. Everything works fine except for the "save()"...

Comment: At least contain all variables inside above code snippet and the relevant control flow with `character`.

Comment: @eth3lbert I updated the code showing an sample variable declaration. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I could not find out the problem with insufficient code information.

Comment: No problem, thank you for reading. Unfortunately, my code is very convoluted and disorganized (working on that). The snippet I added does reproduce the problem, however. I also find it odd that the problem is intermittent. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.